# Как извлечь содержимое msi пакета?

Tags: windows, установка

Как извлечь содержимое msi пакета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось просто:

```
msiexec /a package.msi /qb TARGETDIR=PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Я пользовался утилитой [MsiEx](http://www.wasm.ru/toollist.php?list=15#275)